# How to set color to the packets from different agent in ns2?

Tags: tcl, ns2, linux-mint, packets

Can we set color to the nodes as well as to the packets (packets from different agents like tcp or udp) at the same time?

Answer (score 0):

Yes , you can.
To set color to the nodes

`$node1 color "red"`

and to set color to the packets , you need to first add the following code to your Tcl script , preferably at the beginning after the simulator object has been created, since this is a part of the simulator setup.

```
$ns color 1 blue 
$ns color 2 red
```

where ns is the simulator object.

Now to set these colors to the agents , add the following code after the agent has been initialized

```
$tcp fid_ 1
$udp fid_ 2
```